# How can I format displaytag total value row in export pdf?

Tags: java, displaytag

I'm using displaytag to export PDF. If I give, total="true" in display:column, last row contains total of amounts and I can format that value using numberformat but in PDF total value is displaying unformatted. Below given is my code snippet.

```
 <display:column property="discountAmt" titleKey="DiscountAmt" 
                 total="true" format="<%=currency_format%>"/>

 <display:column property="orderGrandTotal" titleKey="GrandTotal" 
                 sortable="true" format="<%=currency_format%>" class="numeric" 
                 total="true"/>
```

In table, the last row which contains total values are like 1,913.30 and  12,033.50. But in PDF its showing as 1913.3 and 12033.5.

Please give me an idea to format this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<display:column property="money" format="{0,number,0,000.00} $" sortable="true" />
```

check if works.
check http://www.displaytag.org/10/tagreference-displaytag-12.html for more.